# What's the downside of too many parameters?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I thought the downside of too many parameters was that it required too many memory and slowed down the computation until I read the 
 [cs231n class notes from Stanford](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#case) . Here is a quote down from the **VGGNet in detail**, which seems to tell a different story:

> As is common with Convolutional Networks, notice that most of the memory (and also compute time) is used in the early CONV layers, and that most of the parameters are in the last FC layers.

However, in the [computational considerations](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#comp), they say

> From the parameter sizes: These are the numbers that hold the network parameters, their gradients during backpropagation, and commonly also a step cache if the optimization is using momentum, Adagrad, or RMSProp. Therefore, the memory to store the parameter vector alone must usually be multiplied by a factor of at least 3 or so.

As far as I understand, the above quote implies that the parameter sizes do affect the memory requirement and memory computation.

Then I tried to compare the memory cost of the representation and parameters. According to the second quote, if I understand it right, the memory used for the parameters in the first FC layer should be at least $100M*3=300M$, which is way larger than the memory calculated in the case study of VGGNet, $24M$.

Now I get confused, why would they say the most of the memory and also compute time is used in the early CONV layers? Is there anything I understand wrong?

Comment: Of course, the *other* downside is that the more parameters, the easier for the model to just memorise the training set...

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. But here I'm more concerned with memory and computational efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "memory" in the first quote and in their analysis of VGG is only the memory of the activations and not the memory of the weights.

Usually the amount of memory needed to store the parameters compared to the activations is small. VGG has a somewhat unusually large number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Did you suggest that my calculation of the memory in the second last paragraph was right?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.